# Create a self contained exe with a COMReference

Tags: c#, .net-core, compilation, exe, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to publish a self contained exe file.

Sadly all my google work was not helpful. I have a COM reference in my code to the WindowsInstaller.

So far this is my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>MSI_Info</RootNamespace>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;win10-x86</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="WindowsInstaller">
      <Guid>{000C1092-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <Lcid>1033</Lcid>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Isolated>False</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Code is hosted here https://github.com/SmuSmu/MSI-Info

Not so easy to get a simple exe file :)

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? what did you already try? i don't know what exactly doesn't work for you.

Comment: I like to have one single exe file. But after compile there is still some links to dll's and it won't run without it. Even copying missing dll`s to the publish dir will not help.

Comment: when you say self contained exe, do you mean to say that the app should run without the dll file as a dependency in the output folder ?

Comment: How did you even get it to build? The .NET Core version of MSBuild does not support COMReferences

Comment: Try the `/p:PublishSingleFile=True` option (which AFAIK only works with the `dotnet publish` command)

Comment: @MindSwipe COMReferences wirks in VS 2019. Thats why I added that Tag. :) So I do not use dotnet publish because that will fail because I need to use the VS 2019 Compiler

Comment: What files do you see that you don't want? Publishing it from VS2019 gives me an exe and a pdb file (the pdb file is debug info which can be deleted safely)

Comment: but running that 22 MB exe file gives Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MSI Info.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Interop.WindowsInstaller', version: '1.0.0.0'
    path: 'Interop.WindowsInstaller.dll'

Comment: Puttung Interop.WindowsInstaller.dll from debug file to publish folder is not fixing that